# Как добавить генетический алгоритм к Direction API?

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, генетический-алгоритм

Интересно, есть ли способ реализовать простой генетический алгоритм, который решает проблему TSP (имеется в виду, что он находит кратчайший путь из одного места в другое, не посещая то же самое место снова). Я использовал Direction API, однако он уже автоматизирован, и его использование стоит денег. Мне нужен генетический алгоритм, который будет выполнять ту же работу, но я запутался и не знаю, как использовать с Directions API. Я получил файл API JSON с данными о расстоянии и продолжительности. Могу ли я использовать его в качестве параметров для генетического алгоритма и, наконец, но самое главное, как я могу отобразить это на карте.

На данный момент у меня есть экран того, что я могу сделать с помощью Directions API. Я хочу того же, но используя генетический алгоритм. Приложение, которое я создаю, предназначено для Android, поэтому я использую только JAVA. Thx!

Какие-либо идеи на этот счет?

---

[Directions API Screenshot](https://biseamon.imgur.com/all/?third_party=1)

Comment: А в чем тогда у вас будет заключаться генетический алгоритм, если вы сразу с апи хотите брать набор маршрутов тз А в В со списком времени?

Comment: Хм, что я хочу так это создать аналог для Directions API с использованием генетического алгоритма? Я вот посмотрел на примеры, но все они показывают его результаты в логе в ввиде списка а не на самой карте. Мне как бы не принципиально чтобы он данные брал с DIrection API. У меня вот к примеру есть Places API, может он подойдет больше?

Comment: Тут как раз визуализация не самое главное) самое главное - сам алгоритм. Для начала вам надо составить список фич с помощью которого будет производиться оценка времени, затрачиваемого на дорогу. А визуализация достаточно простая. Представьте, что это один большой граф и раскрашивайте его ребра

Comment: На счет фич можно поподробнее? Это тип методы? А это время ведб нужно из Directions API взять или как?

Comment: На основе чего вы планируете создавать свой генетический алгоритм, какие входные данные ему требуются, какие будут выходные, какой архитектурой вы хотите его получить. Пока я понимаю, что вы просто хотите получать готовый результат с DAPI

Comment: По данным у меня сейчас это ширина и долгота входные, на выходе мне нужно получитьdistance и duration. Про архитектуру можно и в виде списка, но лчше уж как направления на карте. Как-то так.

Comment: Вы что, просто берете напрямую расстояние из точки в точку, основываясь только на широте и долготе?) Допустим. Как вы дальше рассчитываете время и дистанцию от точки до точки?

Comment: Ну время и растояние между местами у меня уже готовы. Они находится в JSON файле. Тоесть есть точное растояние между одним пунктом и другим. Всего точек 20.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104765/discussion-between-vladimir-afanasyev-and-marin).